# How do I display a column from a data frame as a bar chart in r?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am new to R and trying to create a bar chart using the barplot() function. The problem is the height needs to numeric. The column of data I need pass is non numeric.

```
counts <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"
barplot(as.matrix(counts), beside = true)
```

What I want is to get a bar chart that has heights 1 thru 3 on the y axis. On the x axis I want to see a bar with a height of 3 for dogs, 2 for cats, and 1 for mouse.

Comment: Try `barplot(table(counts),beside=T)`. To use `barplot` you need to pass it the frequencies of each value

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

By ggplot2 it will be:

```
ggplot(data = as.data.frame(counts), aes(x = counts)) + geom_bar()
```